# Prove that for each $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ there is a subsequence such that $m(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{n_{k}}) \geq \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{E_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-empty Lebesgue measurable subsets of the interval $[0,1]$ which satisfies the following.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(E_{n})=1$.

Prove that for each $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ there is a subsequence -- call it $\{E_{n_{k}}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ -- of $\{E_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $m(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{n_{k}}) \geq \epsilon$.

Sorry I don't have a lot of effort to show because I'm not sure how to go about proving it. My textbook gives a few properties about similar families of measurable functions, but they aren't seeming that useful to me. They are more for proving functions and the sequences' limits are measurable, which is less complex than this.

I do know that if some $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}$ then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. $x$, and that a family of integrable functions is dense in $L^{1}$ if for any $f \in L^{1}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $g$ in the family so that $||f-g||_{L^{1}} < \epsilon$.  It seems helpful but I am not sure how to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: if $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets contained in $[0,1]$. Then $m(A\cap B) \geq m(A)+m(B)-1$.

Proof: Note that $m(A\cup B) = m(A)+m(B)-m(A\cap B)\implies m(A\cap B)=m(A)+m(B)-m(A\cup B)\geq m(A)+m(B)-1$.

Given $\epsilon>0$ let $\chi=1-\epsilon$

We take a subsequence $B_1,B_2,\dots$ such that $m(B_n)\geq 1-\frac{\chi}{2^n}$.

We now prove by induction that $m(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^n B_n)\geq 1- (\chi/2+ \chi/4+\dots \chi/2^n)$.

All we have to do is apply the lemma to $B_{n+1}$ and $(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^\infty B_n)$. Notice that the sum of their measures is at least $2-(\chi/2+\dots+\chi/2^{n+1})$, so $m(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^{n+1} B_n)\geq 1- (\chi/2+ \chi/4+\dots \chi/2^{n+1})$.

Now use the theorem of convergence of measure, we have:

$m(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^\infty B_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}m(\bigcap \limits_{i=1}^n B_n)\geq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}1- (\chi/2+ \chi/4+\dots \chi/2^n)=1-\chi=\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your explanations (like naming the theorem) so that I can research and study more about it.  You answer is very clear. I have to look at it some more before I accept as an answer, but it helps a lot.

Comment: happy to help.${}{}$

Comment: Would you mind showing your induction steps?  I am confused by the part "All we have to do is apply the lemma to $B_{n+1}$...."  You mean we need to apply the rule for $B_{1}$ to $B_{n+1}$ in order to prove for $B_{n}$, right?  Everytime I try to perform induction, I get $m(B_{n+1}) = \epsilon$...

Comment: no, just use the lemma on the following two sets: $B_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B_n$. You know that $m(B_{n+1})\geq 1-\frac{\chi}{2^n}$ and you know that $m(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B_n)\geq 1-\frac{\chi}{2}-\frac{\chi}{4}-\dots - \frac{\chi}{2^n}$.

Comment: Oh! I misread/misinterpreted you before.  Now I see what you're saying; thanks!